# Is its possible to implement CAST-like analysis with SonarQube?

Tags: code-analysis, sonarqube, pmd, static-code-analysis

In my (huge) company we mostly use two tools for code analysis:

- Sonar(Qube) - in the development, tightly integrated with CIs, known and loved my developers.
- [CAST](http://www.castsoftware.com/) - required by the processes. No continuous measurements, only a couple of times a year, for instance on major releases. CAST analysis is completely decoupled from the development, done by a separate team (we just send the delivery package to analyse).

I'm on the dev side as you may guess, I (somewhat) know Sonar/PMD, but not CAST. In any case I'm not quite happy with the frequency of the CAST analysis, but It is probably not the process I could influence or change.

So I was thinking if it maybe would be possible to implement in Sonar similar rules as in CAST. Surely not all and not everything but at least something that there would be no big surprises from the CAST analysis of releases.

I googled all over, looking for something like "PMD rules for Sonar/PMD" but could not find anything.

My question ist for those who have experience with both Sonar and CAST:

**Is it possible to implement CAST analysis rules (or a certain approximation thereof) in Sonar?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know both tools, CAST and SonarQube.
The answer to your question will be technology dependant: which languages are you using for your developments? Are you using any framework?

Don't tell me just J2EE, because this covers a lot of different languages: Java, JavaScript, JSP, HTML, ... not talking about frameworks (Spring, Hibernate, Struts, ...) and each solution will have different analyzers for these languages with different rules.

The main thing between CAST and SonarQube is that both use lexical analyzis to identify violations to programming best practices, but CAST also identify links between components (reason why it's slower). So CAST will have some metrics like fan-in/fan-out and some additional rules (that they name architectural or structural), like avoid direct access from presentation layer to data layer. Also, it comes with some xml files to analyze framework components.

This kind of rules could represent an additional 20%, but again this is very language dependant. And also of the versions of both tools as the number of rules may be different between releases.

And no, I think that not all of these 'architectural' rules would be possible to implement with SonarQube. However, they are not all very critical so you don't miss so much.

I suppose you company use CAST as some Quality Gate? 
In that case, I would recommand to work with the guys using CAST in order to identify which CAST rules are critical for them and could trigger a NoGo or KO. Just post these rules here, and I am sure you will get some good comments about it.

Do not hesitate to ask for further precision.
Regards.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the elaborate answer.
We're on J2EE with JSF and (in my project particularly) JavaScript, underpinned by JPA/Hibernate on JBoss stack. So, sure, lots of stuff. We do have QGs but I don't think CAST analysis would bring a KO. I was actually told that CAST was a kind of "industry standard", with standardized rules and metrics. So I was naively searching for "CAST rules for PMD/Sonar". Hm, I don't feel like diving into CAST interna...
Thank you for your hints.

Comment: I suppose that people who bought CAST in your company will tell you that it is a standard, given the price they paid it. Especially, if they use it only twice a year and won't KO any version of your app. The 'standard' label is probably the only value they can pretend to have bought.

Comment: If you focus on Java/Javascript, CAST will not have much more rules than SonarQube and nothing critical. If we add that CAST is not really a tool for dev because does not go well into a Continuous Integration process, and SonarQube has a better, more valuable interface, don't loose time with CAST.

Comment: I think the only value CAST could have would be on Hibernate, if you want to avoid defects like one on your dev is accessing directly the DB without going through Hibernate. But even in that case, I would recommand you publish the rules that you would like to have in SonarQube. Regards.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I think I'll talk to the chief architect about that.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the set of available rules in SonarQube should cover 99% of the rules you're checking with CAST. If you can't find a valuable rule from CAST in the SonarQube's set, feel free to inquire on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

We use sonarqube in our development envinronment in the company, but in my project the client uses CAST as SQ tool. Almost all CAST rules are covered by sonar rules, for those that are not, we write it using XPATH based on squid java plugin (Sonar 3.8+ if I remember well).

With XPATH we covered the 99% of the CAST rules, we write 30 rules more or less. You can find more information about in this link, there are a tool for test de XPATH rules based on AST representation of a class too (linked in the link below).

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Extending+Coding+Rules

By the way, our project is based on Java, Oracle Web Center Sites, spring, cxf and JPA/hibernate

Hope helps, cheers